# How can i split a string by dot, comma and newline with removing whitespaces by using regex in javascript?

Tags: javascript, regex, split

I have string like this:

```
what, be inclined to, hi . hello 
where
```

I want to split it like this:

```
["what","be inclined to","hi","hello","where"]
```

Currently I'm using this regex but It doesn't work like I want:

```
input_words.val().replace(/^\s*|\s*$/g, '').split(/\n|\s*,|\./);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`split` function alone would be enough. The below regex would split your input according to one or more commas or dots or newline characters along with the preceding or following zero or more spaces.

```js
var s = "what, be inclined to, hi . hello\nwhere";
alert(s.split(/\s*[,\n.]+\s*/))
```

Comment: `split(/[,\.\s]+/)` is enough, isn't it?

Comment: @EricLeibenguth no, it removes the spaces which exists between `inclined to`

Comment: @Sam give an example along with expected output, but I solved the current question.

Comment: I guess I couldn't explain it. I putted &nbsp because can't add multi spaces in this comment line. Could you add this property to code "white space remover"? 1 space is ok but 2 or more isn't.

Comment: you mean this `s.split(/\s*(?:[,\n.]|&nbsp)+\s*/)` ?

Comment: I just want to remove multiple spaces except for one space.

Comment: then `s.split(/\s{2,}/)`

Comment: then do replace `s.replace(/( )+/g, "$1")`

Comment: Oh ok I understand sorry. Thank you very much Avinash.

Answer (score 0):

```
var test ="what, be inclined to, hi . hello\nwhere";
var elements = test.split(/[,\n.\s+]+/) || [];
```